# PostGIS integer loop

Tags: postgis, distance, loop

PostGIS is very new to me, and I'm having difficulty performing an operation that probably isn't too difficult. I have vector layers each filled with the outline of a landmass through time. I want to query the distance between these landmasses for every matching timestep. I can do this manually:

```
select a.gid from_gid, b.gid to_gid, st_shortestline(a.geom,b.geom), st_distance(a.geom,b.geom) as distance
from
(select * from gavdos
where year=3) as a,
(select * from crete
where year=3) as b;
```

The 'year' value ranges in integers from 0 to 21. It would be convenient to do this query using a FOR loop. I am however highly unsuccessful in doing so, the pgAdmin III SQL thing already presents an error when I say `DECLARE i integer;`, thus before I am even ready to try and create a loop.

My question is if someone could give an example how I can (1) set-up the loop and (2) how to get the full output (as I suppose I need to update a table at every step in the loop..).

Thanks in advance! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to do this with a [JOIN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-join.html) instead of a loop:

```sql
SELECT 
      a.gid AS from_gid
    , b.gid AS to_gid
    , st_shortestline(a.geom,b.geom)
    , st_distance(a.geom,b.geom) AS distance
FROM
    gavdos AS a
LEFT JOIN
    crete AS b
ON 
    a.year = b.year
```

If you really need to have a loop and do advanced processing which cannot be accomplished with simple SQL you can have a look at [PL/pgSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html)

Comment: Ah, that is a great solution! I hadn't realised explicit loops are less common in SQL type scripts. Thanks a lot!